# How to find count of array item based on supplied value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array.

```
var a=[{t: "titi", v: 0, id: 100},
{t: "titi", v: 1, id: 101},
{t: "random", v: 2, id: 103}];
```

I have above array. I need to find the objects' count which have 'titi' as it's t value. In this case it need to be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to get the array of matched property value, then take the `length` of the array:

```js
var a=[{text: "titi", value: 0, id: 100},
{text: "titi", value: 1, id: 101},
{text: "random", value: 2, id: 103}];

var count_titi = a.filter(i => i.text=='titi').length;
console.log(count_titi);
```